# Recaptcha provided by Google is not 100% accurate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, recaptcha

I am using Recaptcha using the following link
http://www.google.com/recaptcha

But, I observed, it not 100% accurate.
It validates as success, if we type 2-3 letters wrongly.

Is there a setting, which will make it 100% accurate.

[image]

Now, If a user types "tentace veri", it still validates SUCCESS.
Why can't it be 100% accurate.

Comment: I don't think your users will like doing four captchas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Recaptcha only knows about one word, it's using crowdsourcing for the other, that's why it says "digitizing ..." it's actually using humans to digitize pieces of books.  You could type  in tentace helium and it would work.  There's even an internet movement to replace the second word with a dirty word.  You can tell which one it knows about because it distorts it.